# Where am I going wrong with returning an IEnumerable<T> from an async method?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, ienumerable

I have

```
    public static async Task<IEnumerable<ParseTask>> GetArchiveTodos()
    {
        using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(SharedInfo.ConnectionString))
        using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("GetArchiveTodos", connection))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            await connection.OpenAsync();
            SqlDataReader row = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            while(await row.ReadAsync())
            {
                ParseTask pageToParse = new ParseTask()
                {
                    Id = row.GetInt32(0),
                    PageType = row.GetString(1),
                    Html = row.IsDBNull(2) ? null : row.GetString(2),
                    ThreadId = row.IsDBNull(3) ? null : (int?)row.GetInt32(3),
                    PageNum = row.GetInt32(4)
                };
                yield return pageToParse;
            }
        }
    }
```

and I'm getting the error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1624  The body of 'ArchiveDb.GetArchiveTodos()' cannot be an
>   iterator block because 'Task>' is not an
>   iterator interface type

Comment: You cannot have async methods with iterator block (`yield`), because required return type for iterator block is `IEnumerable`, not `Task`.

Answer (score 1):

> Where am I going wrong with returning an IEnumerable from an async method?

This is simply not supported. You cannot have a `Task<IEnumerable<T>>` returning method be an iterator, i.e.; you cannot use the `yield` keyword. There has been proposals for this [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/1410), but this has yet to be supported. The required return type for an iterator is `IEnumerable` not `Task` - as Evk stated in a comment.